# Integrate Spring in Jax-RS

Tags: spring, jax-rs

Is it possible to intergrate Spring in JAX-RS-API? We wan't use no implementation of JAX-RS (no imports of Jersey, CXF, etc. in our Java code)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible.
You will define `@Path` and `@Component` with jax-rs import. 
You will define `@Controller` with Spring annotation.
The link between both will be made by the applicationContext or by annotation.
So, in my opinion yes, you can.

Comment: Do you have any example?

Comment: Jax-RS is a specification, so your web server has surely an implementation. Therefore, any tutorial of developing REST web services will be good. The only one thing that will change is where to find the javax.ws.rs.jar.

Comment: Thanx. We used Jersey. With Jersey it's easy ti use spring. Now the implementation is apache wink ( we use Websphere 8.5 ) But we have not guarantee that IBM not changed this implementation. So we won't have any import of apache wink.